# How to highlight all identifiers starting by '@'?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I would like to highlight any expression made of letters and that starts with one @. The use of `moredelim=*[s][\color{blue}]{@}{\ }` works only in case like `@name` is followed by one space. The following code nearly works except that I do not want the parenthesis to be colored in case like `@decorator(x=3, y='some text')` because that is `@decorator(` which is caught.

```
moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{gray}]{@}{\ },
moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{gray}]{@}{(},
```

The use of `moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{gray}]{@}{(}` is not a good solution because the search is done on several lines... :-(

Comment: In text editors capable of regular expression identification, just search and highlight this string: `^@.*?`  But how is this a tex question? Do you want LaTeX to do this as it compiles?

Comment: `listings` is one LaTeX package.

Comment: ah - thanks for the clarification and this is good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the same approach as in my answer to [Can the listings package highlight by regexp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/can-the-listings-package-highlight-by-regexp).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter

% ``state variables''
\newif\ifincomment\incommentfalse
\newif\ifinstring\instringfalse

% language and style definition
\lstdefinestyle{mybash}
{%
  language = bash,
  basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue},
}[keywords,strings,comments]

% --- patch to automatically highlight identifier starting by @
% (only outside strings and comments, though) ---
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\@ddedToOutput}
\lst@AddToHook{Endgroup}{\incommentfalse\instringfalse}

% local variables
\newif\if@identifierStartsByAt@
\newcount\currentchar

\def\splitfirstchar#1{\@splitfirstchar#1\@nil}
\def\@splitfirstchar#1#2\@nil{\gdef\@testChar{#1}}

\def\@testChar%
{%
  % copy the first token in \the\lst@token to \@testChar
  \expandafter\splitfirstchar\expandafter{\the\lst@token}%
  %
  % reset switch
  \@identifierStartsByAt@false
  %
  % equality test
  \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter`\@testChar=`@%
    \@identifierStartsByAt@true % if equality, set switch to true
  \fi
  %
  % apply class style if not within string or comment
  \if@identifierStartsByAt@
    \ifincomment
  \else
    \ifinstring
      \else
        \def\lst@thestyle{\lst@keywordstyle}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\let\@ddedToOutput\@testChar
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mybash]{text.txt}
# This is an example
@Blueword(foo) @Blueword bar
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date. As of `listings` version 1.8b I get several `\end occurred when \if... was incomplete` warnings. The output still looks correct.

Answer (score 12):

This is possible.  The package provides the command `morecomments`, which can be used to declare a sequence of arbitrarily delimited symbols to be a comment, and set up its unique formatting. The command

```
\lstset{morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{@}{\ }}
```

means that any sequence of symbols (`[s]`) delimited by `@` and space, will be typeset in blue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\lstset{language=bash}
\lstset{morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{@}{\ }}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
# This is an example
@Blueword # This will be done properly
for x in *~; do
  echo $x;
done
# This too
@Blueword x
for x in *~; do
  echo $x;
done
# And this one
@Blueword 
for x in *~; do
  echo $x;
done
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for `{\ }`. That's what I've been looking for...

Comment: I've updated my question because there are some drawbacks...

Comment: Unfortunately listings does not accept multiletter delimiters (yet?), so in your example you need to write `@decorator (arg)`.  By the way, I know at least one company, where a space between function name and opening bracket is required by the coding style.