# How can I automatically highlight SuperCollider symbols and environment variables?

Tags: listings, highlighting

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`sclang-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sclang-prettifier)

I've been poring over the `listings` manual, trying to figure out how to get some very specific types of formatting for the SuperCollider language.

I need to highlight words where the opening delimiter is `\` and the closing delimiter is any non-alphanumeric character. **Background:** SC has a normal string type, delimited by double quotes -- that's easy. It also has a Symbol type, in single quotes (also easy) -- *but* Symbols that consist only of alphanumeric characters (and underscore) may also be written with a preceding backslash: `'symbol'` and `\symbol` are equivalent.

Note that the answer to [How to highlight all identifiers starting by '@'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51540/listings-package-how-to-highlight-something-that-starts-with-one) does not apply because the closing delimiter may be *any* non-alphanum (frequently a comma or closing paren, in which case it would be ugly to force a space before it).

If `listings` won't do it, what alternatives do I have? I also looked at the `minted` manual, but that was even more confusing.

Some sample SuperCollider code:

```
p.clear;

~grains.addSpec(\tfreq, [1, 40, \exp]);
~grains.addSpec(\overlap, [0.1, 10, \exp]);
~grains.addSpec(\pos, [0, b.duration]);  // 3.43 is nice!
~grains.addSpec(\rate, [0.5, 2, \exp]);
~grains = { |tfreq = 25, overlap = 6, pan = 0, amp = 0.2, pos = 3.43,
   rate = 1|
   var trig = Impulse.ar(tfreq);
   TGrains.ar(2, trig, b, rate, pos, overlap / tfreq, pan, amp)
};
~grains.play;
```

`\exp`, `\tfreq`, `\overlap`, `\pos` and `\rate` need to be highlighted as Symbols. Ideally, environment variables (e.g. `~grains`) would also be highlighted in a different color (same rule but with a different opening delimiter).

I have another question, which I will ask separately...

Comment: I don’t think `minted` supports SuperCollider; at least, it’s not in the list of lexers I get from `pygmentize -L lexers`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listings` can do that, but you have to whisper in its ear `:)`

First, tell `listings` to treat backslash and tilde as "letters", thereby allowing them in identifiers. Then, before each identifier gets printed, check the first character of that identifier and apply a different style depending on that character.

For convenience, I've defined keys to easily specify the styles for SuperCollider classes (starting by `A-Z`), symbols (starting by `\`), and global variables (starting by `~`).

**Update**: For convenience to SuperCollider users, I've put together a little package called [`sclang-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sclang-prettifier), now available on CTAN and, soon, in popular TeX distributions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{sclang-prettifier}

% --- write source code to external file (for this example) ---
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.scd}
p.clear;

~grains.addSpec(\tfreq, [1, 40, \exp]);
~grains.addSpec(\overlap, [0.1, 10, \exp]);
~grains.addSpec(\pos, [0, b.duration]);  // 3.43 is nice!
~grains.addSpec(\rate, [0.5, 2, \exp]);
~grains = { |tfreq = 25, overlap = 6, pan = 0, amp = 0.2, pos = 3.43,
   rate = 1|
   var trig = Impulse.ar(tfreq);
   TGrains.ar(2, trig, b, rate, pos, overlap / tfreq, pan, amp)
};
~grains.play;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting
[
  style      = SuperCollider-IDE,
  basicstyle = \scttfamily\small,
  caption    = {SuperCollider sample}
]{sample.scd}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  frame   = single,
  caption = Some code unrelated to SuperCollider,
]
 c = a
 a = b
 b = c
 discard c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It looks great. Sorry I didn't reply quickly; I was busy writing content. Question: There seems to be a bug, though. It works correctly for the first listing, but all subsequent listings have a large number of extra "a" characters sprinkled throughout, e.g. "// aProxySpace asyntaxa" with 3 extra "a"s. If I comment out the first listing and recompile, then the next listing is correct and all subsequent ones fail. I suspect some state variables are not being reset properly. I also suspect it's an easy fix :)  and I'm really grateful for your work on this.

Comment: @James There is indeed a bug and it probably is an easy fix, but I won't have time to look into it until late today. Stay tuned. In the meantime, please also have a look at my answer to your other question.

Comment: @James The bug has been corrected in the latest version of  `supercollider.sty`. Grab it from https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/supercollider and test it on the code posted in my answer. Let me know if you notice anything else that looks like a bug. If you're happy, please upvote/accept my answer(s). Also, please let me know whether you think I should make this an official package and submit it to CTAN. Would SuperCollider users in general be interested in it?

Comment: I have tested it on my own code (just made a small reproducer here: https://github.com/jamshark70/scweek2014/blob/master/shows/full-article/listings-test.tex). It passed that test, and also rendered an entire chapter correctly as a test. It doesn't work with beamer, though: chokes on `{\lst@FontAdjust`. I can live without that for now, but that should be fixed before making an official package. So now it's just: tweak the colors, remove the border and run the whole thing.

Comment: I will accept this answer now, but I've also logged an issue at bitbucket for the Beamer problem.

Comment: @James Thanks for your feedback; there was indeed a bug, but I seem to have fixed it in my latest commit; please test it and confirm. Also, things are not set in stone yet. Do you have any suggestions for the package? In particular, do you think I should rename the `globalvarstyle` key to `envvarstyle` or something similar?

Comment: @James I don't use SuperCollider myself and I'm familiar neither with the language nor with the terminology. However, based on this [2012 post of yours](http://new-supercollider-mailing-lists-forums-use-these.2681727.n2.nabble.com/global-variables-td7421932.html#a7422054), I've decided to rename the `globalvarstyle` key to `envvarstyle`. If you find other bugs or if you think of additional features for the package, please open an issue on the Bitbucket page. Also, since you're a SuperCollider power user, please don't hesitate to advertise the package to the SuperCollider community `:)`