# Set Python's decorators in some colour but keep @ as an operator unchanged

Tags: listings, python

I am using `listings` for code formatting and colouring in a document I'm working on, including a lot of Python code. I would like for decorators to be displayed in a specific colour but for the `@` symbol to still be displayed normally when used as a matrix operator.

I found a *hack* to handle the decorators on this website (unfortunately a long time ago and I can't seem to find the original post) using a *delimiter* with `@` as left delimiter and `\^^M` as right delimiter. The following code then succeeds at showing the decorator in orange, but also shows the matmul operator in orange.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{.9,.5,.1}
\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=python,
  moredelim=[s][\color{orange}]{@}{\^^M},  % show decorators in orange
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle={\ttfamily},
  tabsize=4
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
@decorator
def function():
    A = B = np.eye(5)
    A = A @ B
    A @= B
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

How could one keep the specific colouring for the decorators but leave the operators (i.e. either  `@`  or  `@=` ) in black? I tried to understand how [this proposition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163138) by [jub0bs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jub0bs)  works to adapt it but my knowledge of `listings` (and LaTeX for that matter) is far from enough for that.

Comment: You could look at the [`piton` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/piton) if you are using `lualatex`, it has options for `@decorator`'s, the author of the package is active on this site too which is nice. Could use `listings` for your non-Python and `piton` for Python. If you want to stick with `listings`, hope someone can answer!

Comment: If possible, I'd like to keep a `listings`-based solution to not enforce `lualatex` on the other people working on this document (`pdflatex` is the standard compiler here), but I'll try `piton`, thanks for the recommendation!